# Trying to access modules page callback while authenticated

Tags: hooks, routes

I have a module below that will only show "hello world" when I am an administrator. I would also like "hello world" to display when I an authenticate user but right now all I am getting is you are not authorised. I have set  mymenuitem as the home page and I am using Drupal 7.

```
 function mymenuitem_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['mymenuitem'] = array(
    'title' => 'mymodule',
    'description' => 'my menu access issue',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_homepage',
    'access arguments' => array('access mymodule homepage'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  return $items;
}


function mymodule_homepage(){
  drupal_set_title(t('menu system'));
  return "hello world";
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suspect you're logged in as user 1, who by default has permission to view all the menu links of the site; hence you are able to see this page. The other users are not able to view it because you did not define the permission (the value provided in `'access arguments'`) mentioned. You do so by following the method shown by @Aiias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure you define your new permission using Drupal 7's [`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7).
2. Grant your new permission to `authenticated user` here: /admin/people/permissions/list

Try this:

```
function mymodule_permission() {
  return array(
    'access mymodule homepage' => array(
      'title' => t('Access My Module homepage'),
      'description' => t('View My Module homepage.'),
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to implement any custom permissions. However, OP mentioned that he needs to show this to _authenticated_ users not _anonymous_, so you might want to change the point #2 to accommodate it.

Comment: @develkar - Nice catch. I have changed my answer accordingly :).

Comment: That worked perfectly and it was one hook I was missing thanks

Comment: @purencool - No problem, happy to help :)

Comment: @purencool - If this answered your question, please mark your question as answered so others can refer back to this answer and StackExchange will not consider this as an open question.

Comment: It does but how do you check it as answered

Comment: @purencool - There's a checkbox just beneath the down-vote arrow. If you click that, it will mark your question as answered by this answer. Here is the official `how-to` page: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers